# In my admin section, use same layout, but add an additional css and js file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

In my admin section, I want to use the same layout as my other website, but I want to add an additional CSS file and JS file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your controller sets a variable `isadmin`, check for it in the corresponding view.

If it is true, include the files.

**Controller:**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @isadmin = true # probably calculated somehow
  end
end
```

**View:**

```
<head>
  <% if @isadmin then %>
    <script />
    <link />
  <% end %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout:

```
<%= yield :additional_scripts %>
```

In your views, where you want to add those scripts:

```
<% content_for :additional_scripts do %>    
# Include scripts here
<% end %>
```